# Is possible to create main menu and options menu with nested canvases in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas

The project is a 2D platformer for Android devices. I created a main menu with animation on one canvas and an options menu with animation on another canvas. My goal is to have a transition between the two when a button is clicked.

Images:
[Main Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agUJS.jpg), [Options Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q87U7.jpg), [Main Menu On Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H265i.jpg)

I tried to create a nested canvas with these two other canvases but I get an error on the canvas scaler component - non-root canvases will not be scaled. UI Scale Mode is Scale With Screen Size. The menus dissapears in the bottom left corner, barely visible.

No script yet

I expect to create a script or a controller to switch between these canvases. I saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Z4AuSQtLv0 but there is just one canvas and the UI elements are nested on different panels. Is this possible with canvases?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make 2 different scenes, one for each menu. The best thing about this is modularity and ease of use, you just swap scenes when needed. Keep in mind for the Pause Menu Scene that you must swap to it additively so you don't destroy the game Scene.
Call the animation on each one when menu is swapped (just before swapping scenes):

```
//Here you play the animation
SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

If you have placed the game and the menus in the same scene, split them, managing your game with scenes is the way to go.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Comment: Thanx for the help. I created the scenes as suggested. Now, what I need to do is create a game manager object and than its script? And into which scene I put the game manager. Am I on the right path? If you have some tutorial to this, can you post it here. Many thanx.

Comment: After reasearch I applied the code but after build I tested it on my Android an there is a lag, Something is not right with the frames. When the menu is applied into a one scene as a Canvas object there is no lag at all, its working smoothly but as a LoadSceneMode.Additive I have a lag.

Comment: You need to optimize the game, when you load as additive both scenes are in memory, and your game eats resources that's why it's lag.